# Can I change KSQL table from AVRO to JSON format?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to have a JSON format table for my python script to access it and doesn't want to change the original topic format as it is currently in AVRO format.

So my question is, it is possible to change from an AVRO format to JSON format? Either from stream to table, or from table to table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the alternative `VALUE_FORMAT` and create a derived stream/table:

`CREATE STREAM foo_json WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON') AS SELECT * FROM foo_avro;`